# c++ int pointer to array of pointers to arrays memory leaks

Tags: c++

so I have this class with a functions.hpp and a functions.cpp

```
#include "function.hpp"

test::test(int size)
{
    this->size = size;
    matrix = new int*[this->size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[this->size];
    }
}

test::~test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        delete[] this->matrix[i];
    
    delete[] this->matrix;
}
```

but this still produces memory leaks, I am using the CRT library to test this

```
#include "function.hpp"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    int size = 10;
    test test(size);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

this code still dumps memory leaks on me, and I've followed several tutorials and I'm starting to doubt either the CRT library or my computer.

Comment: Why are you not using vectors? Any specific reason? Or maybe,... even smart pointer will do. In a nutshell. avoid using `<data-type>*` in C++

Comment: I did try to use vectors in my main program but I felt it cumbersome since I have some structs inside one of the arrays. Im thinking of going over to vectors but it still bothers me that this doesnt work.

Comment: "I felt it cumbersome" why? vector is *more* applicable to user defined types, because it doesn't default construct them all at once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the destructor is not called until `main` is exited which is **after** you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`. Change your code to this

```
int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    {
        int size = 10;
        test test(size);
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

The extra `{}` ensure that the destructor is called before the call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`.

A different techique would be to write a class to perform the check.

```
class LeakCheck
{
public:
    LeakCheck() { _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF); }
    ~LeakCheck() { _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }
    LeakCheck(const LeakCheck&) = delete;
    LeakCheck& operator=(const LeakCheck&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    LeakCheck _checker;
    int size = 10;
    test test(size);
    return 0;
}
```

Because destructors are called in reverse order of constructors, it's guaranteed that `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` will be called after the destructor of `test`.

I want to call `LeakCheck` a *shim class* but apparantly that's not the right terminology, maybe someone can tell me the correct term in the comments.

Comment: I think the closest to the term you want, in terms of wide use, is "scope guard", though personally I don't find it to be the best name in general.